# How to create (Add To Compare) in wordpress posts

Tags: php, functions

I have a new custom type post called cars. And I'm going to create a page to **compare cars**. On the single page of each car, there is a table of technical specifications using the [ACF plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Do you know a tutorial on how to do this system by storing the ID of each car in the user's browser cookie and use it in my compare page query?

I am going to create a simple button (add to comparison list) on the single page of each car. So that users can add their desired cars to the comparison list.